# Google Image preview like slide down preview for Twitter Bootstrap grid gallary

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have elaborated the problem at the link below, its the same problem as I am stuck in right now but just a snippet extraction.

Link: http://www.bootply.com/134032

If you click any of the boxes here, the slide down does work but it only occupies 1/3 of the container and the rest it overflows in the background.

Another apporach I tried was to set this css but even thought that fixes the issue of slide box occupying 1/3 of the div, it'd add a major glitch to the design as the clicked button would always automatically move to the right-most side.

```
.og-expanded{
    float: none;
    /*float: left;*/
    position: static;
}
```

I have been stuck at this problem for 2 days now and I need help with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your detailed version of the image is in a `col-xs-12`, you should really just have to toggle it `hidden` or not when clicking the "view it" link, with some simple javascript. That will take up the whole row, and push other content down the page.

```
  <!-- Thumbnail -->
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="//placehold.it/400x300">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Big-Image -->
  <div class="col-xs-12 hidden"><!-- use js to add/remove class"hidden" on button click -->
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="//placehold.it/1200x900">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>HighRes</h3>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**http://www.bootply.com/oSGM0jOG6q**

I don't have the javascript toggle at hand, but if no-one else comes along, I may come back and do it:)